# Using Q promise library with Express.js and Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise, q

I've never used promises and am exploring them using an express.js/mongo app I wrote. Below are one of the routes that query mongo and then set the result as a property on an object in the render method arguments ( to be used by the template engine). **I am curious how to write this in a "promise" style [using Q](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q).** I've been fiddling for about an hour and decided to throw in the towel and ask.

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    Comment.find(function(err, item) {

        res.render("index", {
            comment: item

        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are not persistant that it has to be done on `q`, you can use `bluebird` and promisify:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
Promise.promisifyAll(Comment);

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    Comment.find()  // now this is already a promisified method
        .then(function(item){
            res.render("index", { comment: item });
        }).catch(function(err){
            res.render('error', { error: err });
        });
});
```

I don't think `q` has such promisification method, so, in q, using `deferred`:

```
var Q = require("q");
app.get("/", function(req, res) {

    var deferred = Q.defer();
    Comment.find(function(err, item) {
        if(err)    return deferred.reject(error);
        deferred.resolve(item);
    });

    deferred.promise
        .then(function(item){
            res.render("index", { comment: item });
        }).catch(function(err){
            res.render('error', { error: err });
        });
});
```

Comment: You'll want to read https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#interfacing-with-nodejs-callbacks :-) Btw, deferreds are deprecated, you should use the `Q.Promise` constructor.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks for the heads up, truth be told, I do not have much experience with bluebird/ q promises, I am curious as to why `deferred` is being deprecated everywhere, I know that is the case with bluebird also, same for [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Deferred) apparently, but unable to find the reason why

Comment: Basically because the revealing constructor pattern has a nicer, conciser syntax (doesn't need an extra `deferred` variable) and also catches exceptions from the resolver callback.

Answer (score 0):

You'd use [`Q.ninvoke`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qninvokeobject-methodname-args) to get a promise for the `item`:

```
var itemPromise = Q.ninvoke(Comment, "find");
```

Now you can chain a `.then` to that - basically attaching two callbacks:

```
itemPromise.then(function(item) {
    // success case
    res.render("index", {
        comment: item
    });
}, function(err) {
    // error case
    res.render("index", {
        comment: undefined // reflecting your original code, but hardly what you want
    });
});
```

In this case, promises don't have lots of advantage. You cannot use them for `app.get` btw, as that might be an asynchronous callback, but for multiple events not for a single result.